# IntelliJ doesn't generate metamodel classes after configuration (with gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, metamodel

What I did so far:

1. `Enabled annotation processing` in idea's preferences and selected `Obtain processors from project classpath`, then selected `Module content root`
2. Added `compileOnly group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-jpamodelgen', version: '5.6.0.Final'` dependency to `build.gradle`
3. Built the project

I can see the route `build/generated/sources/annotationProcessors/main` where main is a generated source route but it's empty and no metamodel classes there.

I can find these simple steps everywhere but unable to create metamodel classes.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue with the following additional dependency: `annotationProcessor group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-jpamodelgen', version: '5.6.0.Final'`

Just for future reference.